# Performing Loop Unrolling while iterating the hashmap

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, iterator, hashmap

I am looking at a possibility of unrolling the loop which is written to iterate the elements in a hash map.Below posted is the code.

```
for (final Object key : map.keySet())
{

    if (input_map.containsKey(key))
    {
        System.out.println("Matching key: " + key);
        if (map.get(key).equals(input_map.get(key)))
        {

            System.out.println("hii!done");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(key);
            final String values =
            key.
            toString().
            substring(key.toString().lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            System.out.println("input_map" +
            input_map.get(key));
            System.out.println("map" + map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:
 Currently, comparison in the loop is being  done based on one element at a time i.e "key".I am looking at a possibility where i can retrieve the next successive keys in one single iteration i.e(key,key+1,key+2).

Any Suggestions would be highly helpful.

Comment: why? It's the same amount of work to compare 10 individual keys as is comparing 2 at a time times 5.

Comment: The code is wrongly formatted, please update it

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve with this code actually? give us a sample scenario where this makes sense?

Comment: @MartinHenriksen i'm trying to reduce the computation time by doing multiple loads in one cycle

Comment: But if do 3 at a time or 1 at a time, you still have to do n computations and n get() calls where n is the elements in the map.

Comment: @mohanbabu You do not reduce the computation time by getting entries in threes. You still have to call `next()` the same number of times. By doing this you are just making your code harder to follow for no gain at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `KeySet` or `EntrySet` `iterator()` method and `while` loop through with `hasNext()` and `next()`. You need to handle cases where it has not 3 repeating elements. Then you have the 3 keys and should be able to easily access the values in the `Map`.

```
Iterator<Integer> it = myMap.keySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{
    int first = it.next();
    int second = it.next();
    int third = it.next();
}
```